# React - Call props function inside of a components function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to do something like this:

// Component one

```
toggleDropdown() {
  setState({open: !open}
}

render () {
  return (
   ChildComponent toggle={this.toggleDropdown} />
  )
}
```

Then in my child component I'd like to call that toggleDropdown function in another function like this:

```
// This gets triggered on click.
removeItem() {
  // remove scripts then:
  this.props.toggleDropdown()
}
```

I thought you'd be able to do something like this but it appears that you can only call prop functions on the element?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The prop that you are passing down to the child component is named `toggle` and not `toggleDropdown` and hence you need to call it like that in the removeItem component

```
// This gets triggered on click.
removeItem() {
  this.props.toggle()
}
```

Other things that you might need to do is to bind your `removeItem` function using `bind` or `arrow functions`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
}
```

or

```
// This gets triggered on click.
removeItem = () => {
  this.props.toggle()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just call `toggle` instead of `toggleDropdown`.

```
this.props.toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

The child component's prop is named `toggle`, while `toggleDropdown` belongs to the parent component.

This should work in the child component:

```
removeItem() {
    this.props.toggle();
}
```